# How can I get the component at the mouse click position, when using a TableCellEditor?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, tablecelleditor

I use a custom `TableCellRenderer` with multiple `JFormattedTextField` in the table cells. I use the same component as `TableCellEditor`. Now I need to know in what `JFormattedTextField` the user clicked, and also where in this field (can be done with `viewToModel`).

When using a custom `TableCellEditor`, the only way to get the `Point` from the mouse click is the [`isCellEditable(EventObject e)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#isCellEditable%28java.util.EventObject%29) method in `CellEditor`. The `Point` given is in the parents coordinate system.

> anEvent is in the invoking component coordinate system.

But how can I get the component at the clicked coordinate? I have tried with [`findComponentAt(Point p)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#findComponentAt%28java.awt.Point%29) but it returns `null` for me.

Here is some code I have tested with:

```
@Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {

        if(e instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent ev = (MouseEvent)e;
            Point p = ev.getPoint();

            // gives strange values
            Point p3 = editor.getLocation();

            // x: 0 y: 0
            Point tp = ((JTable)e.getSource()).getLocation();

            // these returns null
            Component c1 = renderer.findComponentAt(p);
            Component c2 = editor.findComponentAt(p);

            System.out.println("Click at " + p + " editor at: " + p3);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The values for the component's location `editor.getLocation();` gives almost random values for the y-coordinate (e.g. when using 5 rows in the table).

**How can I get the component the user clicked on when using a `TableCellEditor` and a `TableCellRenderer`?**

---

Here is a full example:

```
public class FormattedTableEditDemo extends JFrame {

    public FormattedTableEditDemo() {

        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        MyTableCellEditorAndRenderer cellEditorAndRenderer =
                new MyTableCellEditorAndRenderer();     

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(BigDecimal.class, cellEditorAndRenderer);
        table.setDefaultEditor(BigDecimal.class, cellEditorAndRenderer);
        table.setRowHeight(40);

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    class MyTableCellEditorAndRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor
            implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

        MyCellPanel editor = new MyCellPanel();
        MyCellPanel renderer = new MyCellPanel();

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, 
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            renderer.setValue(value);
            return renderer;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            editor.setValue(value);
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {

            if(e instanceof MouseEvent) {
                MouseEvent ev = (MouseEvent)e;
                Point p = ev.getPoint();

                // gives strange values
                Point p3 = editor.getLocation();

                // x: 0 y: 0
                Point tp = ((JTable)e.getSource()).getLocation();

                // these returns null
                Component c1 = renderer.findComponentAt(p);
                Component c2 = editor.findComponentAt(p);

                System.out.println("Click at " + p + " editor at: " + p3);
            }

            return true;
        }

    }

    class MyCellPanel extends JPanel {

        JFormattedTextField field1 = new JFormattedTextField();
        JFormattedTextField field2 = new JFormattedTextField();

        public MyCellPanel() {

            field1.setColumns(8);
            field2.setColumns(8);

            field2.setValue(new BigDecimal("0.00"));

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(field1, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));
            add(field2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        }

        public Object getValue() {
            return field1.getValue();
        }

        public void setValue(Object value) {
            field1.setValue(value);
        }
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        List<BigDecimal> values = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

        public MyTableModel() {

            // test values
            values.add(new BigDecimal("37.00"));
            values.add(new BigDecimal("4305.90"));
            values.add(new BigDecimal("386.04"));
            values.add(new BigDecimal("3486.58"));
            values.add(new BigDecimal("6546.45"));
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            return values.get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return BigDecimal.class;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FormattedTableEditDemo();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for sscce, but why not listen to the desired field itself?

Comment: @trashgod: It doesn't receive a `MouseEvent` when it's used in a `TableCellEditor` unless the cell already has focus. `isCellEditable` is the only way I can receive the `MouseEvent` when clicking on a row that doesn't have focus.

Comment: No, I mean skip the `MouseEvent` altogether and add a suitable (action, property, etc.) listener to each `JFormattedTextField`.

Comment: @trashgod: I don't understand that suggestion. I need to use the coordinate from the `MouseEvent` but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't understand the goal, so it's hard to suggest a specific listener. For example, adding a `FocusListener` will identify the source and destination of navigation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand what's going wrong (just let me know if I'm off, so I can delete this :-)

Assuming you want to get the "real" component under the mouse (click/press) which triggered the start of editing, the trick is to do the conversion (from parent to editor coordinates) *after* the editor is added to its parent. That's guaranteed for shouldSelectCell, but not for isCellEditable (the latter being called *before*)

A [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119718/treecelleditor-must-select-cell-to-edit-even-if-shouldselectcell-return-false/8279716#8279716) in the context of a tree (should be similar enough) has some runnable example. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
/**
 * At this point in time the editing component is added to the table (not documented!) but
 * table's internal cleanup might not yet be ready
 */ 
@Override
public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
    if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
        redirect((MouseEvent) anEvent);
    }
    return false;
}

private void redirect(final MouseEvent anEvent) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MouseEvent ev = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(anEvent.getComponent(), anEvent, editor);
            // at this point you have the mouse coordinates in the editor's system
            // do stuff, like f.i. findComponent
            ....
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 In retrospect, one can see that `p3` was showing the _previous_ position.

Comment: @trashgod: ah, that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question but an explanation of the result you see: [`findComponentAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#findComponentAt%28java.awt.Point%29) returns `null` because "there is no child component at the requested point." `MyCellPanel` is located on a [`CellRendererPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/CellRendererPane.html) used by `JTable` to speed rendering. There's an example of how it's used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776211/230513).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the table's row and column from the clicked point. Then call the same renderer's getTableCellRendererComponent method to get renderer component. Then correct point subtracting previous rows' heights from y and previous cells' widths from x. Then get proper child of rendered component.

Comment: But how do I get "proper child of rendered component"? I can't get it with `findComponentAt()` in this case either.

Comment: You can write own findComponentAt. Get all children and for each of them get bounds and check whether event x/y (corrected ones) are in the bounds.